# Problem installing SQL Server client tools

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2005, installation

We are tring to install SQL Server 2005 Standard on Windows 2008 Standard both 64 bit. Have done this before with no problems.

This time we get an error during the installation of client tools:

> There was an unexpected failure during
>   the setup wizard
>
> Link Id 20476, message ID 50000

There are no errors in the event log.

Anybody have any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into something that before where 32-bit piece of the client tools got installed prior to my installing the 64-bit client tools.  This is also the suspect of [**this debacle**](https://serverfault.com/questions/14952/sql-server-2005-patch-corrupts-sql-installation-on-windows-2003-standard-x64).

As you're perusing your setup log from joeqwerty's answer keep an eye out for this clash, even if you haven't (or even don't think you have) installed the 32-bit client tools.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the SQL Server setup logs. Here's an excerpt from sqlmag.com on where the log files are located:

*You might already be familiar with the SQL Server 2005 Setup log, which is located at %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\LOG\Summary.txt. If the summary.txt log file shows a component failure, you can investigate the root cause by looking at the component’s log, which you’ll find in the %Program-Files%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\LOG\Files directory.*